# How do I find threads that belong to the same process in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process, linux-kernel

Since a `task_struct` is allocated for each thread in Linux, how to I find the threads that belong to the same process?

So, that was the general question. To elaborate, I need to write a kernel function that traverses the threads that belong to a process (p), given  a pointer to its `task_struct` or pid, and do something with them (e.g. collect some information).

Comment: Added an update, you can list the subdirectories of `/proc/[pid]/task`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`linux/sched.h` has this function:

```
struct task_struct *next_thread(const struct task_struct *p);
```

And other supporting functions, such as `get_nr_threads()`.

You'll have to iterate like e.g.

```
struct task_struct *t = task;
do {
    /*....*/
    t = next_thread(t);
} while (t != task);
```

See also code in `fs/proc/` which has a lot of code to traverse processes and threads (whose runtime info is seen in the `/proc/<pid>/` directory tree)

Comment: Would `task` be declared and instantiated as `struct task_struct *task = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);`?

Comment: @Keeler That'd likely be one way, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't need `task_struct` at all.

See [**my gist**](https://gist.github.com/keeler/8383749) for a example code on printing the threads of a process with a given pid.

**Reference**

Type `man proc` at the command line ([online version](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)), and find the entry for **`/proc/[pid]/task`**.

Quoting from the man page:

> This is a directory that contains one subdirectory for each
>   thread in the process.  The name of each subdirectory is the
>   numerical thread ID ([tid]) of the thread.

Note that one of the subdirectories in `/proc/[pid]/task` is whatever `[pid]` is (the pid of the program you're inspecting).

You can then gather other information using the pseudo-files in the directory `/proc/[pid]/task/[tid]` for each thread pid `[tid]`.

**Without C Code**

`ps -mo THREAD -p <pid>` should work.

Comment: I was thinking more within the linux source code. I was searching for a command line kind'a thing. So, something like 'task->threads_list'

Comment: Did that work for you, though? You tagged no languages on your question, and didn't ask for code, hence why I answered with `ps`. If you're actually after a way to do this in code, specify what language, and edit your question to show code you've tried. If not, mark this as the answer if it works for you. :)

Comment: Linux kernel is written in C. Yes, I did not clearly state it. But I kind of hinted at it when I mentioned the task_struct.

Comment: Thank you for the tip though. I edited the question to better explain what I need.

Comment: Well, I know that. :) Now I see where you're coming from.

Comment: I wanted to write kernel-space function. @nos 's answer suits my purposes the most. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: @hebbo Yeah, I already upvoted his answer. :) I just wanted to put this answer up to show that it's possible to do without any kernel internals.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the field

```
 struct list_head ptrace_list;
```

contained in task_struct

This [link](http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg11186.html) describes it as

> list of parent that traces the process

You would then traverse it with

```
 list_for_each_entry()
```

.